# I've posed this question re "quasi-dual" 1_22's offline to George Hart

Tags: combinatorics

I've posed this question to George Hart off-line - if you're not familiar with his site, it's a wonderful place to visit:

http://georgehart.com/

Question:

The Wiki on E6 here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)

gives the coordinates for the symmetric coordinatization of 1_22 in 9-space, and in this coordinatization, there are two opposed sets of 27 vertices, plus another two opposed sets of 9 vertices each, for a total of 27+27+9+9 = 72, as required.

Since the 1_22 has 54 "hemi-penteract" or "hemi-5-cube" facets, I am assuming that it is possible to construct a 1_22 such that the centers of these facets are 54 vertices of a second 1_22 - in particular - the 54 vertices that divide into the two opposed groups of 27 each in the 9-space symmetric coordinatization of 1_22.

Is this assumption true?

If so, would you happen to have coordinates somewhere around that show the construction?

Here is the answer to the question, kindly provided by Dr. Richard Klitzing:

https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/mo.htm

His answer to the question is "no", but he has provided an even more interesting construction which will serve the same purpose in an even better way:

T'is an interesting idea, what you had asked below. So I first had to have a look too.
You'll find a lot about that polytope 1_22 = mo already online at https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/mo.htm .

E.g.
* its radius is 1 (in units of edge lengths)
* its 5-faces are all hins (cf. corresponding links in the above mentioned webpage)
* its 4-faces are either hexes or pens (each: dito)

One deduces further that the one but next vertex distance of mo is sqrt(2) = 1.414 (in units of edge lengths).
On the other hand one calculates the dihedral angles to be one of the followings:
* hin-hex-hin = 120 degrees
* hin-pen-hin = arccos(-1/4) = 104.478 degrees

Therefrom one deduces (as their complements) that the dual of mo has 2 edge types,
* the smaller has a centri angle of 60 degrees
* the larger has a centri angle of arccos(1/4) = 75.522 degrees
Scaling that dual so that the smaller edge length size would be 1, then the longer one becomes 1.225

As 1 < 1.225 < 1.414 it becomes clear that the centers of the 5-cells of mo do NOT provide a subset of an other mo's vertices.

OTOH, at the bottom of that mentioned page you'll find a true subdivision of these vertices of mo into 6+6+6+27+27,
according to 2 mutually tri-dual trittips (again: dito) plus 3 mutually perpendicular (planar) hexagons.
You even will find a link to the according diminishing oddimo, which rejects these 3 hexagons from its span/hull.
Thus oddimo relates to mo in a similar way as the great antiprism (gap) does to the 600-cell (ex).
Moreover it is obvious from the according linked page that oddimo happens to be a scaliform polytope.

--- rk

Comment: @MoisheCohen - from this question, it should be clear why I was/am so interested in minimal root and minimal weight diagrams, and the way in which these diagrams are at least "metaphorically" related to how Loeb use used "Dirichlet domains" and "coordination polyhedra" in his discussion of the properties of crystallographic lattices.

Comment: I have an answer to this question from Dr. Richard Klitzing in Germany, and it is a very interesting answer.   But I am waiting for his permission before I post it. Here is a link to Dr. Klitzing's page: https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/mo.htm

Comment: I have posted Dr. Klitzing's answer in the thread . . . it's a VERY interesting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nine-dimensional coordinate system given at the wikipedia page, is not really nine dimensions at all.  Three axies are used to give two dimensions, in the style of (x,y,z):x+y+z=0.  So the coordinates really are tri-hexagonal.

The E6 has a construction in terms of a 'body-centred hexagonal'.  This is what the wiki page is trying to show.  Let's look at how this works.

The hexagonal tiling has three 'stations', or places it can stand with the same symmetry.  These are at the vertices (0), the 'up-pointing' triangles (1) and the down-pointing triangles (2).

The vertices of the E3 lattice then correspond to (0,0,0), (1,1,1), (2,2,2).  This gives a grouping of three hexagons around a vertex in (0,0,0), and (1,1,1) and (2,2,2), are tri-triangular prisms, the three triangles are inverted relative to the first set.

So 1_22 are the 18+27+27 points at distance 1, being three hexagons at right angles to each other, and two tri-triangular prisms, the first is inverted on all three triangles relative to the second.

The other 2_22 correspond to the vertices (0,1,2),(1,2,0),(2,0,1) as one set, and (0,2,1),(2,1,0),(1,0,2).  Relative to a point in (0,0,0), the 27 points in each of these sets are 2_21 = /4B and 2_21 = 4/B, one a central invert of the other.

The three stations of 2_22, when taken in prism-product with the hexagonal, gives (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), being the E8 tiling.  This gives the 'magic star' configuration of 4_21, being a hexagon, a pair of triangle-2_21 prisms, centrally inverted, and a core figure of 1_22.  The arrangement is a hexagon, with an pair of inscribed triangles (the prisms occur at the six vertices of the inner hexagon), and the core is at the centre, as 1_22.